# Icons not change after delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

After deleting a record in a tree-view grid, the icons not change.

For example, a parent with a single leaf only: when I delete this single leaf,  I'm expecting to see the parent's icon change to a leaf icon because it has no children anymore.

Only if I physically reload the page, the currect icons are seen.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the leaf with the file and non-leaf with the folder. Even if you remove all files from the folder the folder (non-leaf) will be not converted to the file (to leaf). So the behavior which you expected is not correct at least in the common case.

**UPDATED**: Probably if you would use "ui-icon-folder-open", "ui-icon-folder-collapsed" and "ui-icon-document-b" (see [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery%20UI%20CSS%20Framework)) instead of default "ui-icon-triangle-1-e" "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" and "ui-icon-radio-off" (see [treeIcons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid#options) option) all will be more clear.

Comment: In my case, i'm not working with files and folders but with boss & employees. If a boss doesn't have employees anymore than the boss is not a parent and should be showen as a leaf.

Comment: As for your update, as I told you, i'm not working with file-system.

Comment: In some countries the boss without employees will be interpreted still as the boss (:-)), but it's not really important. What you can do is to reinsert the tree node with respect of `delTreeNode` and `addChildNode`.

Comment: Managers of themselves?   ;-) Do you have some example for your solution?

Comment: @Yair: Probably the problem is in the exact word which you use. The managing director of the company stay the managing director (the boss) event if it has no employee. The salary and the position (the status) in the company will be not changed if the number of employees will be reduced. The head of department stay the head of department even the department will consist of one person. I said before that your main question could be solved using TreeGrid methods.